# Boolean OR doesn't seem to work in Youtube APIv3 list search (or PHP SDK)

Tags: php, youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I've been trying to search for videos matching one of several keywords on a specific channel to which I'm connected. I'm using the Officiel PHP SDK and here's what I have :

```
//client is a connected Google_Client
$youtube = new Google_Service_YouTube($client);
$pageToken = null;

$res = $youtube->search->listSearch(
    'id, snippet', [
        'maxResults' => 50,
        'q' => "foo|bar",
        'forMine' => true,
        'type' => 'video',
        'pageToken' => $pageToken
    ]
);
```

This will only return videos containing BOTH "foo" and "bar", instead of EITHER "foo" or "bar". I've also tried "foo | bar", "foo%7Cbar", "urlencode("foo|bar)", "foo||bar", but none of these give me what I want.

Am I missing something ?

Thanks.

Comment: If you mean "either/or", then you're probably looking for `xor`, not `or` (which is "either or both").

Comment: @lenz Thanks for the clarification I am actually looking for "either or both", and I'm getting only those containing "both".

I just want to achieve what's described in the documentation :


_Your request can also use the Boolean NOT (-) and OR (|) operators to exclude videos or to find videos that are associated with one of several search terms. For example, to search for videos matching either "boating" or "sailing", set the q parameter value to boating|sailing._

edit : now I see the documentation describes an "XOR", but I suspect it's implied that videos matching both would be returned too

Comment: The code above works fine for me (with the | and no encoding). What happens if you remove the `forMine` parameter? You should get hundreds of `Foo` fighter videos with no `bar`s and `King of the bar` with no mention of `foo`!

Comment: @theduck you're absolutely right, it works fine without the forMine parameter.

I don't really know where to go from there, but at least it's a start ;-)

Thanks.

Comment: Do you get the same issue with the API explorer? ie. with forMine set to true do you still have only videos with both terms being returned?

Answer (score 1):

From the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list):

> To search for videos matching either "boating" or "sailing", set the q
>   parameter value to boating|sailing.
>
> Note that the pipe character must be URL-escaped when it is sent in
>   your API request. The URL-escaped value for the pipe character is %7C.

Just tested your case and it works like expected, `title` column contains "foo" OR "bar".

https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?q=foo|bar&type=video&maxResults=50&key=YOUR_API_KEY&part=snippet

```
"title": "KING OF THE BAR 2015 - Ultimate Calisthenics Battle!",
...
"title": "Foo Fighters",
...
"title": "Foo Fighters - Something From Nothing",
...
"title": "Browning BAR M1918",
...
"title": "Bar \"u Szwagra\" - Video Dowcip",
```

So, issue should be in PHP SDK.